# URL token valid?

Tags: php

I am reading this book Essential PHP Security by Chris Shiflett where I came across using tokens (Session Hijacking) in URL. The book says "A better approach is to propagate a token in the URL - something that can be considered a second form of identification.

**Example**

```
<?php

$token = md5(uniqid(rand(),TRUE));

$url = array();
$html = array();

$url ['token'] = rawurlencode($token);
$html['token'] = htmlentities($url['token'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


?>

<a href="index.php?token=<?php echo $html['token'];?>">Click Here</a>
```

Once I hit "Click here", the url now has a token to it

```
http://localhost/urltoken/index.php?token=55420e8dce399820ecf4dfa08cf0d5a0
```

What I do not understand is how does the server knows whether this token is valid or not.

Comment: You can eventually put the token in the  $_SESSION[] and then compare it with the token present in the 'url'.

Comment: @Franco, can you give me an example please.

Comment: The token can be stored in a database.

Comment: @Barmar, yes he could also save it in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the token in a database table that has foreign key(s) referencing the user table and any other tables relevant to the application. When the user goes to the link with the `token` parameter, the script than looks the token up in this table. If it can't be found, the token is invalid.

A common example of this is when you create an account at a web site, and it sends you an email to validate the account. The link in the email will contain a token that refers back to the account, and when you click on it the script will mark that account as validated. Password reset emails work similarly.